# CSS not getting picked up when site is deployed

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm new to MVC and ASP.NET in general and while trying to teach myself I've ran into a problem.

I have a very simple MVC3 site that is working fine when I run it through vs2010. However when I deploy it on iis 5.1 and browse to localhost/MySite the page will load but the CSS is not being picked up.

In my Site.Master I have:

```
 <link href="../../Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

In my _Layout.cshtml I have:

```
 <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

I assume I'm doing something stupid and it's looking in the wrong place for the Site.css. Any ideas?

Comment: Silly question first; is your folder hierarchy the same on the server?

Comment: If you click on the css file in Visual Studio is the `Build Action` set to `Content`?

Comment: Build Action is set to content and the hierarchy is the same, it's in mysite\Content\